# Am I using the Linux or Ubuntu platform?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems

I am not sure if this question goes here, but I was wondering about the relationship between Linux and Ubuntu. I read on-line that Ubuntu is a "flavor" or "variation" of Linux(http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081115235208AAudJ4h), but then one of my classmates said they are the same thing. If I am asked what platform am I using, do I say Linux or Ubuntu?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Ubuntu is a kind of Linux the way a poodle is a kind of dog. If somebody asks what kind of pet you have, do you say it's a poodle or a dog?

Comment: Well, first I would say a dog. Then if they asked what kind, I would say a poodle. So, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu is "a kind of linux" (the exact word is a "distribution").

But there are lots of other distributions of Linux.

So saying that you use linux or that you use Ubuntu: both would be true. The latter would be more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Linux itself is not a full O.S its just a kernel.
Ubuntu is full featured O.S using linux as its kernel.

Comment: If you want, Windows also consists of NT kernel and userland applications. Linux is comparable to NT kernel, whereas Ubuntu is comparable to Windows. Debian, Fedora etc. are different operating systems, which are built on top of Linux and share some of userland applications.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is a computer operating system based on the Debian Linux distribution and distributed as free and open source software, using its own desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of confusing you more: if you want to be completely precise, you could say that you're using the Ubuntu distribution of [*Gnu* / Linux](http://www.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-linux-faq.html#why).

Answer (score 0):

> the relationship between Linux and Ubuntu.

Linux is a kernel.

The job of a kernel is, basically and simply, the run the computer, managing resources (programs have to ask the kernel for access to things like memory and devices) and making sure all processes/programs running on the system don't step on each other.

A kernel by itself does nothing, it's like having an engine that's not installed in any car.

You need actual programs that "run under" the kernel to do things like provide your desktop, command line utilities, open and edit your documents, etc.

Linux distributions like Ubuntu wrap these programs up in packages, which you can install or uninstall as you like or need.  The Linux kernel itself is available as a package, and installed during setup.

Some packages don't do much on their own, but provide libraries and support software for other packages that might use it.  So under Ubuntu, when you install a package, it may want you to install additional dependencies as well.  Typically this happens automatically without you needing to worry about it - but if you look at what's installed you'll see a lot of libraries and such for this reason.

You'll get a complaint from the package manager if you try to uninstall a support package needed by something higher up, like a library needed by `firefox` for example.